# Why dots in the icons?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

These are my icons as I expected

[image: icons]

BUT after I set

```
width: 31px !important;    
height: 31px !important;
```

They look like this:

[image: dotted icons]

Why they got those dots? How do I fix it?

```css
.btn-datatable {
    background-color: #F4A800 !important;
    border: none !important;
    color: #1F2D32 !important;
    width: 31px !important;
    height: 31px !important;

}
```

Comment: Seems like an `ellipsis` problem I'd suggest `text-overflow: clip;` , however if you can please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Parco That was it! Thanks! Can you answer the question so I mark it as correct? What is ellipsis? Thanks again.

Comment: you should first provide a code otherwise the question and the answer are useless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused due to a property regarding what to do when the text overflows, it's bigger than its container, there are some ways to handle it. The most common ones are `clip` which basically cuts the text up to wherever it fits and `ellipsis` which is the use of `...` to denote that there is more content. You can read more about it at [text-overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow).

```css
div {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrap {
  white-space: normal;
}

.ellipsis {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.clip {
  text-overflow: clip;
}

.container {
  width: 121px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrap">Looooooooooong text</div>
  <div>Short text</div>
  <div class="clip">Short text</div>
  <div class="ellipsis">Short text</div>
  <div class="clip">Looooooooooong text</div>
  <div class="ellipsis">Looooooooooong text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Happy to help mate